# Interfaces and Inheritance: Accessing Inherited Methods from Dependency Injected Class

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, interface

Here's my scenario:

```
Public Interface IFlow
End Interface

Public Class Base
   Protected _var1 as String
   Protected _var2 as String

   Public Property Item(str As String) As String...

   Public Function Func() As String...
End Class

Public Class MyFlow
Inherits Base
Implements IFlow
...
End Class

Public Class ServiceCaller
   Private _flow As IFlow
   Public Sub New(ByVal flow As IFlow) 
     _flow = flow
   End Sub

   Public Function Test() As String
     _flow.Func() <--- Can't call this
   End Function
End Class
```

I've ran into this before, but I was wondering if there was a good explanation. I'm assuming it is because the interface doesn't have those methods within the code contract. I get that. What is the best way to implement this type of functionality where I have a bunch of common methods in a base class, but want subclasses to inherit and be dependency injected into a service class?

Is the best approach to simply put those methods into the interface and call the base methods inside those implemented methods in the subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the methods to several interfaces, I'd propose the following approach:

- Create a base interface with the common methods.
- Derive the interfaces that need the common methods from the base interface by using the `Inherits` keyword.
- Implement the base interface in the base class.
- You do not need to implement the methods again in the derived classes. But if you mark the implementations in the base class as overriable, you are able to override the methods in the derived class if you need to change the implementation in a derived class.

This way, you don't need to add the methods to several interfaces and pass the calls to the base class implementation in each class again.

Comment: Once I laid this out as you explained it, this makes perfect sense. Thanks.